# Pytest fails when using type hints for lists

Tags: python, pytest

If I provide exact typing:

```
def _get_options(self, property_options: list[dict]) -> list[OptionInput]:
```

`pytest` (v.6.2.5, Python 3.7.3) returns an error:

`E   TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

This happens for all types of lists: `list[str], list[dict]`, etc.

but when I change the header to:

```
def _get_options(self, property_options: list) -> list:
```

It works. Same thing with literals:

- fails: `ACCOUNT_IDS: dict[str, str] = {"my_account": "123"}`
- works: `ACCOUNT_IDS: dict = {"my_account": "123"}`

Is there any option in the config that would allow such type hints like `list[dict]` etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `from __future__ import annotations`; you can add this at the top of the module.

The caveat is this won't work with direct assignment in Python versions earlier than 3.9, like `CustomType = list[dict]`.

---

You can also read more on the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) which introduces the `__future__` import to Python 3.7+.